# Laravel Blade Forms : File Old data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have the following code for updating, which is working for text fields :

```
{!! Form::text('username', @$admin->adminName, ['placeholder' => 'Enter the username']) !!}
```

But for files :

```
{!! Form::file('image',  @$admin->photo) !!}
```

It throws the following error :

`Illegal string offset 'name'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Form::file()** does not support old input. Check `FormBuilder` class, method `file`.

By the way, how do you expect it should work? Uploaded file will not be stored in session.

Second parameter for **Form::file()** is options **array**.

Comment: File input is only for selecting files through browser. You cannot put `filename` there with **value** attribute.

Comment: can you show an example according to my code, Please

Answer (score 0):

The simplest form of this method is to only pass the name.

```
{{ Form::file('thefile') }}
```

This creates a very simple element which looks like the following.

```
<input name="thefile" type="file">
```

**To add other attributes, pass a second argument to the method. This second argument must be an array.**

```
{{ Form::file('thefile', ['class' => 'field']) }}
```

Now the input has a class attribute.

```
<input class="field" name="thefile" type="file">
```

Comment: I think this error coming by other code. Please check you have used name column from database table. And, name column does not exists in query or not in table.

Comment: No name is not used !

Comment: {!! Form::file('image',  @$admin->photo) !!}

This way , you will not show image.

Comment: I am not showing image, I am updating an existing image name. If its wrong this way why the above code is working ?